# Onunload event of body tag is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I need to use onunload event of body. But its not working. I have following code for that. Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>

 <body onunload="myFunction();">  
 </body>
 </html>
 <script type="application/javascript">
 function myFunction()
 {
    alert("hello");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want so show an alert on unload? Or what do you want to say?

Comment: I need to store some data when the window is close any way and i think so onunlod is only event which so this.

Comment: Then try `onbeforeunload`. Don't test it with alert though, it won't show on `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got the solution. Thanks to @artm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload=before;
 window.onunload=after;

 function before(evt)
 {
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'addVar.php',
        dataType:'text',
        data:{

        },
        success:function(data){

        },

        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){

        }

});

  //return "asd";//If the return statement was not here, other code could be executed     silently (with no pop-up)
   }

   function after(evt)
   {
   //This event fires too fast for the application to execute before the browser unloads
   }
   </script>
   </head>

   <body >
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 </html>
 <script type="application/javascript">
 function myFunction()
 {
    alert("hello");
 }
 </script>
```

you should use this inner html like

```
 <html>
 <head>
 ....
 <script type="application/javascript">
 function myFunction()
 {
    alert("hello");
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onunload="...">
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `<script>` tag is outside of your `<html>` tag. Try moving it into your `<head>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="application/javascript">
 function myFunction()
 {
    alert("hello");
}
</script>
  </head>

 <body onunload="myFunction();">  
 </body>
 </html>
```